# How was ApiCommand.php works in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I just wonder how ApiCommand.php works in laravel?

**This is my ApiCommand.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use DB;

class ApiCommand extends Command {
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'api:command';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Command description';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */

public function handle()
{
    include(app_path() . '/includes/HelloAnalytics.php');
    include(app_path() . '/includes/DeepCrawl.php');  
    include(app_path() . '/includes/Uptime.php');
}
```

**This is my HelloAnalytics.php**

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
//require_once '/home/vagrant/apps/pc-reporting-tool/vendor/autoload.php';
include(base_path() . '/vendor/autoload.php');
$results = array();
$otherResults = array();
$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
// there are two websites in google analytics account so $i<2 is used
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
$profile[$i] = getFirstProfileId($analytics,$i);

//**** get the property name
$propertyName[$i] = $profile[$i][0];

/* results of a profile is saved with each iteration. The loop iterates
    until all the profile in google analytics account is save */
$results[$i] = getResults($analytics, $profile[$i][1]);
$otherResults[$i] = getOtherResults($analytics, $profile[$i][1]);
}


function initializeAnalytics(){
// Creates and returns the Analytics Reporting service object.

// Use the developers console and download your service account
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = app_path() . '/includes/GoogleAnalytics.json';

// Create and configure a new client object.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

return $analytics;
}


function getFirstProfileId($analytics,$index) {
// Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

// Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
$accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
$items = $accounts->getItems();
$firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

// Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
$properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
    ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
  $items = $properties->getItems();
  $firstPropertyId = $items[$index]->getId();
  //*******************
   $firstPropertyName = $items[$index]->getName();

  // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
  $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
      ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

  if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
    $items = $profiles->getItems();

      //***** stores Property name and Profile Id as an array
      $info = [];
      $info[0] = $firstPropertyName;
      $info[1] = $items[0]->getId();
    // Return the first view (profile) ID.
    //return $items[0]->getId();

      return $info;
        } else {
    throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
     }
     } else {
  throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
     }
  } else {
  throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
    }
  }

function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
// Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
// for the last seven days.
return $analytics->data_ga->get(
'ga:' . $profileId,
'30daysAgo',
'yesterday',      
'ga:users', 
['dimensions'=>'ga:deviceCategory,ga:browser'] */
['dimensions'=>'ga:day'] 
  );
}

function getOtherResults($analytics, $profileId) {
// Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
// for the last seven days.
return $analytics->data_ga->get(
'ga:' . $profileId,
'30daysAgo',
'yesterday',      
  'ga:users,ga:newUsers,ga:sessions,ga:sessionsPerUser,ga:pageviews,ga:pageviewsPerSession,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:bounceRate'
  );
}

function printResults($results) {
// Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
// the profile name and total sessions.
if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

// Get the profile name.
$profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

// Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
$rows = $results->getRows();


$sessions = $rows[1][0];

// Print the results.
//print "First view (profile) found: $profileName\n";
//print "Total visits: $sessions\n";
//print "Total users: $users\n";
} else {
   print "No results found.\n";
  }
}
```

**This is my Uptime.php**

```
<?php 

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.uptimerobot.com/v2/getMonitors",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "api_key=XXXX",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
$data = json_decode($response);
$custom_uptime = ($data->monitors[0]->custom_uptime_ratio);
$uptime = explode("-",$custom_uptime);
}

?>
```

DeepCrawl.php was not done yet.

My problem is I want to use ApiCommand and use that handle function to gather all the data's for my google analytics uptime and deepcrawl but I don't know how it works. Sorry for my bad grammar cause I'm not use to it and I'm just new in the programming environment. Hopefully someone can help me how ApiCommands.php works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: few questions: why are you including HelloAnalytics.php, DeepCrawl.php and Uptime.php? what exactly all the classes do? I think you can import the class and call method that you want to trigger.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What are you going to achieve? From your posted code I can definitely suggest changing includes to `use` declarations. Second thing is, are you sure you are not mixing concepts? It seems that you try to define console command, which can be invoked by hand or by queue runner. On the other hand, you call it somehow API, which may sound like you want to access it via API. If that's the case you should make your command collecting all needed data and storing it somewhere, then you need to create API endpoint where you can fetch this stored data.

Comment: Can you include the contents of `HelloAnalytics.php`, `DeepCrawl.php` and `Uptime.php`?

Comment: @usrNotFound they get report data from the three different sites using api.

Comment: @RossWilson already updated.

Comment: In your question you said "I don't know how it works", do you mean you don't know how console commands work in general. or you don't know how `HelloAnalytics.php` and `Uptime.php` work?

Comment: I don't know how console commands works. @RossWilson

Comment: You have given your command a signature of `api:command` so you would simply run `php artisan api:command` from the command line to execute the handle method of this class.

Comment: @RossWilson thank you. I'll make a new thread about my error on my HelloAnalytics.php. You can actually put that on the answer so I can marked it checked.